# How to edit sender information in Pages' letter template?

Tags: macos, pages

When you create a letter in Pages it creates sender information in the upper right corner. How do you edit this information? If you click it, it just selects everything but doesn't give you a way to change the text.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and the answers below don't address it: I can select the block, but not edit the pieces of information individually so in the process I lose the formatting provided by the template.

Comment: I have the same issue. This is very odd. Anyone solve it?

Answer (score 8):

Okay, I found out how to do this. It looks like the elements in a new document created from a template are setup as Placeholder text.

After creating a new document, select all and then do this **twice**:

```
Format -> Advanced -> Define as Placeholder Text
```

The first time makes sure all elements are setup as placeholder text, and then the second time removes this setting from everything that is selected.

Now everything is editable.

Comment: This is what did it for me, but I had to reselect JUST the address section and remove the placeholder text part from it. So strange that they made this so unintuitive!

Answer (score 3):

You simply click the field you want to edit to select it, then type what you want.

For example, press **⌘N** and choose **Letters** from the **Choose a Template** window and select **Classic Letter**.

Then in the upper right hand corner, click to select the *name*, and type in your name.

Repeat...

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I just stays a colored block of text when I select it. It won't let me edit the sender information.

Comment: @Berry Blue, Then I'd suggest you edit your OP and include information like, macOS version, Pages version and which Template you're using so we can try to replicate your issue.

Comment: @BerryBlue add a screenshot of the whole pages window perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the text, overwrite it and use you own preferences of indent, font size and line space etc.

The template text's settings can be used as reference, for e.g., sender's details are right indent and font size 12.